# Relational Database design for repeat data in a few columns

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

Here's the kind of data I am working with:
There is user data like email id, age etc:

And there is app specific settings data (opacity, speed, volume etc) for which there are default values but user is free to change the defaults and customize the app to their needs.

I would like to have the option to change the default values for existing users without needing to change on a per user basis across the users table.

What would be a good approach to take?

1. Should I have all the data in one table along with a configuration file containing the default values and a flag called default_settings (yes/no).

> ```
> Table: USERS
>
> user_data_1|user_data_2| ... |setting_1|setting_2| ... |default_settings
> ```

2. Or should I have all the user data in one table and link it to a corresponding settings data on another table with the first row of settings table containing default values. There is no categorization of settings. Either it is default settings or a set of custom values

> ```
> Table: USERS
>
> user_data_1|user_data_2| ... |setting_id
>
> Table: SETTINGS
>
> setting_id|setting_1|setting_2| ...
> ```

Thank you.

Comment: No. And No. See normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first design is more relational. Each setting belongs in its own column, with appropriate column name, data type, and a `DEFAULT`. There's no need for a final column `default_settings` in my opinion. Each column either has the `DEFAULT` value, or else a non-default value.

However, that design has the drawback that any time you need to introduce a new setting, you need to use `ALTER TABLE` to add a new column. And there's a practical limit to the number of columns in a table. There may be multi-valued settings, which are hard to model in a single column.

More often what I see for user settings is a second table that references the first. Each user has many rows in that second table, one row per setting:

```
Table USERS
user_data_1|user_data_2| ...

Table SETTINGS
user_id|setting_name|setting_value
```

This design allows for an unlimited number of new settings to be enabled per user, simply by inserting a new row, without `ALTER TABLE` to add new columns.

Default values are kept in the application code. That is, for each setting, if it is not present in the database for a given user, the application code assumes a reasonable default value.

This settings table is basically a "key-value" store, which has different problems:

- Each setting name is stored redundantly, in a row instead of as the column header. The spelling of the setting name can become inconsistent, e.g. "color" vs. "colour".
- You must choose a data type for the setting value that supports any setting, so you lose the support of SQL for enforcing numeric or date formats. I.e. everything becomes a string.
- You lose the ability to store the `DEFAULT` in the column definition.
- You lose the ability to use SQL constraints like `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE`, or `FOREIGN KEY`.

Nevertheless, this pattern is still very popular for this scenario.

Comment: thank you. The problems mentioned for the "key-value" store seems to demand extra caution from the developer and is more prone to invalid entries being added to the database if the developer is not careful. Considering that team members keep changing, I'd prefer to have SQL constraints.

The reason of having a **default_settings** (BOOLEAN) column in combination with a config file is so that if the default setting needs to be changed, it can simply be changed  in the config file and the app can simply pick those settings for the  users for whom **default_settings** is true. Your views?

Comment: Changing defaults in the config is a good reason to do that, but I'd prefer to use NULL in each of the setting columns to signify "use the default". That way you can let the user have the default on a setting-by-setting basis.

Comment: Good point! Never thought I could have "use default" on a per setting basis. Will adopt this approach. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @BillKarwin's suggestion. I have decided to go with Option 1.

```
Table: USERS

user_data_1|user_data_2| ... |setting_1|setting_2| ...
```

The default values in the settings column would be NULL to signify that these settings need to be read from the config file. If the user customizes the setting, the NULL will be replaced with the user defined value. This allows the convenience of changing the default values in one place for all the users on a per setting basis.